# Show $\Bbb{E}\left[ {f\left( \eta \right)\Bbb{E}\left[ {\xi {\text{|}}\eta } \right]} \right] = \Bbb{E}\left[ {\xi f\left( \eta \right)} \right]$

Tags: probability

The question is to show $\Bbb{E}\left[ {f\left( \eta  \right)\Bbb{E}\left[ {\xi {\text{|}}\eta } \right]} \right] = \Bbb{E}\left[ {\xi f\left( \eta  \right)} \right]$ where $\eta,\xi$ are two RVs.

My solution is simply $\mathbb{E}\left[ {\xi f\left( \eta  \right)} \right] = \mathbb{E}\mathbb{E}\left[ {\xi f\left( \eta  \right)|\eta } \right] = \mathbb{E}\left[ {f\left( \eta  \right)\mathbb{E}\left[ {\xi |\eta } \right]} \right]$, but I am not confident with such a short answer.

Comment: Presumably $f$ is Borel measurable so $f(\eta)$ is $\eta$-measurable, in which case your argumentis valid via "pulling out what is known."

Comment: Perfectly correct.

Comment: @Did I am feeling like I am finally starting to understand probability theory despite taking a graduate level real analysis course and measure-theoretic probability course in grad school (master's). Thanks for all the help.

Comment: @Math1000 You are welcome. (Maybe this is unrelated to your ordeal but probability theory is notoriously *badly* taught in tons of curricula.)